# Returning multiple values from a function

Tags: c, function

After reading [this article](https://www.techiedelight.com/return-multiple-values-function-c/) I understand the methods for returning multiple values using structs or pointers (the first two). However, after describing the third method (using a temp array), the author writes:

> We should not use this approach as the variable information is not
> passed to the caller function. For example, we’re using the array’s
> index to retrieve the values of our variables. Also, note that we have
> to allocate the array dynamically in a heap. If we use the static
> array, it ceases to exist when we exit the function, and accessing it
> inside the caller function will result in undefined behavior.

This is the code example the author provides:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
// Function to return multiple values using an array
int* initialize()
{
    // Important: Dynamically allocate memory
    int *temp = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
 
    *temp = 10;
    *(temp + 1) = 20;
    *(temp + 2) = 30;
 
    return temp;
}
 
// Return multiple values from a function in C
int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
 
    int *arr = initialize();
 
    a = arr[0];
    b = arr[1];
    c = arr[2];
 
    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d", a, b, c);
 
    // free memory
 
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what the author means, because I tried this method in a small program I wrote and it seems to works just fine, i.e. I can access the returned array's elements in the caller function. Why is this not recommended?

Comment: As any local variable, an array defined inside a function has the same life-time as the function itself. When the function ends, so does the life-time of all variables inside the function. If you returns a pointer to such a local variable (like the pointer to the first element of an array) that pointer will become immediately invalid.

Comment: It _could_ work once for a particular run of a particular program with particular compilation settings during a particular phase of the moon, but in general it's undefined behavior and will break at any moment.

Comment: The link contains various artificial examples and some of them in obsolete C. So what exactly the author means is anyone's guess. In general, caller allocation is preferred and returning pointers to dynamic memory is bad practice since we _know_ (from 50 years of experience of using bad C libraries) that APIs doing so are to blame for memory leaks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That isn't the case here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was referring to the author's third example which defines and returns the `temp` array, not to the example using pointers. C newbie here, so maybe both are internally the same, I don't know.

Comment: Technically `temp` in that example isn't an array, it's a pointer that is initialized to point to the first element of an array that is allocated dynamically on the heap. And memory allocated on the heap has a life-time for the duration of the program, or a pointer to it has been passed to `free`. There's nothing "static" about the memory or the pointer variable though.

Answer (score 2):

The referenced text is unclear and confusing at best. At worst, outright wrong.

> We should not use this approach as the variable information is not passed to the caller function.

It's unclear what "variable information" means here. The actual values is getting back to the caller so that's not the problem. Maybe "variable information" is supposed to mean something like "information about number of variables" but that's unclear.

> For example, we’re using the array’s index to retrieve the values of our variables.

Yes, well, of cause... If the values are being sent back in a (dynamic allocated) array, we have to use array indexing to get them. That's obvious and not really a problem.

> Also, note that we have to allocate the array dynamically in a heap.

Finally something clear and correct.

> If we use the static array, it ceases to exist when we exit the function, and accessing it inside the caller function will result in undefined behavior.

Here it's very unclear what "the static array" refers to. There is no static array in the code. It seems to be refering to some code only available in the authors head...

If the author is thinking about code like:

```
int temp[3];  // Instead of malloc
```

then the author is correct. But... that's not a static array so ....

If the author is thinking about code like:

```
static int temp[3];  // Instead of malloc
```

then the author is wrong. Due to `static` this array can be accessed from the caller.

So again... very confusing...

To answer your question:

> Why is this not recommended?

Well, some concerns could be:

1. Dynamic allocation is an expensive operation. So don't use it unless you have a good reason.
2. Returning dynamic allocated memory from function and relying on the caller to free it  later on is a source of many memory leak bugs. So avoid doing that.

**BUT...**

Good pratice rules nearly always comes with exceptions.

For instance consider a function that returns a rather huge and unknown number of results. For such a function it can be fine to return a pointer to dynamic allocated memory. But you would also need to return the actual number of results. It could look like:

```
int foo(int ** a)
{
    // Generate results and use code like
    *a = malloc(.. a lot ..)
    ...
    // Perhaps some realloc(.. even more ..)
    ...
    return number_of_results;  // or perhaps -1 on error
}

int * a;
int results = foo(&a);
if (results > 0)
{
    ....
    for (int i=0; i < results; ++i)
    {
         // Do something with a[i]
         ...
    }
    ....
    free(a);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> If we use the static array, it ceases to exist when we exit the
> function, and accessing it inside the caller function will result in
> undefined behavior.

It is rubbish. `static` automatic array will still exist after the function return. It is because such array has static storage duration The function will be not [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)).

The author probably meant *automatic storage duration* array.

Undefined behaviour (UB):

```
int *foo(void)
{
    int array[10];

    /* ... */ 
    return array;
}
```

No undefined behaviour:

```
int *bar(void)
{
    static int array[10];

    /* ... */ 
    return array;
}
```

Comment: @Haris `static` automatic variables have the same lifetime as the program. They exist after function exit and you can access them

Comment: It's not really clear if they meant an array with static size or an array with static storage duration/`static`. Either way, a seasoned C teacher wouldn't use the word static so carelessly. The Internet is full of bad C tutorials.

Comment: Similarly to what I wrote in a comment to my post above, I was referring to the author's third example which defines and returns the `temp` array, not to the example using the `static` keyword.

Comment: @Cirrocumulus I did not follow the *external link*. You need to post the example in **your question**. Read how to post here